# Anchor links inside iframe in iPhone safari not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a page contains link with overlay and iframe in it.
As shown in the image once i click the link from main page overlay with iframe will load but after that once i clicked on the link inside iframe it is not loading a new page as expected.

So i tried with adding a new href by appending a link inside in iframe, that is also not working.
All sources are from same domain as well.

```html
<a href="/links#testing" target="_parent"><strong>Testing page</strong></a>
```

[image: Scenario]

Comment: The solution here seems to have been trivial, and is not recorded in an answer, so I am minded to try to close this question as "typo/norepro" for now.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly: using `target="_parent"` will cause the link to open in the parent window. Is the fix something as simple as you need to use `target="_blank"` to open in new tab?

Comment: I found the solution, the issue is because the events are not triggering inside the iframe so just triggered the events on iframe load, now it working as expected.

Comment: Brilliant, that was going to be my next thought process. Good work